# How to use substitution operator in Oracle Application Express Edition?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I want to get user input and using substitution operator but getting this error:
As this is working in SQL Developer but doesn't working on **Oracle Application Express**
Query-->

select * from emp
where emp = '&emp_name';

Facing this problem:

```
ORA-00904: "EMP": invalid identifier
```

[Query and Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0ajh.png)

Comment: You should try ename = '&emp_name' in your where condition.

Answer (score 1):

Substitution variables are a SQL PLus concept that is also implemented in SQL Developer and SQLcl. It only works in those oracle clients. APEX connects directly to the database, not through a client.

To prompt for user input in the APEX SQL Workshop, use the bind variable syntax. For example:

```
select * from emp where ename = :emp_name;
```